# Find all $6 \times 6$ matrices knowing the trace and $A^3-6A^2+5A=0$

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, trace

I have to find all matrices $A$ that satisfy:

- Trace of matrix $A$ is $17$
- $A^3-6A^2+5A=0$

I have calculated characteristic polynomial $X(X-1)^2(X-5)^3$ and minimal polynomial $X(X-1)(X-5)$, so eigenvalues are $0$, $1$ and $5$. Diagonal matrices with these values answer the question. But how to find **all** matrices?

Comment: All matrices of type :
$$P \mathrm{diag} (0, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5) P^{-1}$$ 
with $P$ an invertible $6 \times 6$ matrix

Comment: Do you know the fact that any matrix whose minimal polynomial is squarefree is diagonalizable?